# After Adding BigCommerce Customer to Group, Send to Emma

Tags: bigcommerce

I am looking for a way to automate adding new customers in BigCommerce to a list in Emma (email marketing). However, I want these customers to be sent AFTER the customer has been added to a Customer Group in BigCommerce.

To further clarify:

1. A user creates an account [on website](https://store-nxbphakg.mybigcommerce.com/login.php?action=create_account) (You can see the extra field with four options)
2. Within BigCommerce, we see that a new account has been created,
3. AND we see that they (hypothetically) selected the "Architects &
   Designer" option.
4. Then we manually add the customer to an actual Customer Group in BigCommerce.
5. Then the customer is automatically added to a specific list in the Emma account.

From what I can tell there is not a way to do this through the BigCommerce API, but would appreciate suggestions on how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: using the api, yes you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The automated solution for this would require [webhooks](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/webhooks).

- Create the webhook to listen for customer updates
- Upon an incoming webhook request, check to see if this update was a customer group update.
- If the webhook requests specifies an update in the customer group, then proceed with your normal Emmy program.

Hope this helps